# Looping and modifying a line row by row

Tags: stata

I am new to Stata's syntax and cannot figure out the syntax to do what I would like:

Let's say that my chart looks like:

```
var1 var2 var3
1.3 4.5 3.3 (row 1)
3.3 2.3 3.6 (row 2)
4.5 1.1 2.2 (row 3)
```

I would like to run a command that I wrote but for all values except each row (that is, I would like to run my program with just row 2+3, 1+3, and 1+2 to give 3 different outputs).

I was wondering how I can make a for loop from say `i= 1` to # of rows and within the for loop:

```
delete row[i]
run the program, give output
insert row[i]
```

I cannot seem to find anything online that seems to fit.

Comment: Are you open to solving this with R too, or is that tag added by mistake?

Comment: I am open to using R as well!

Comment: Cross-posted on Statalist at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/mata/1379902-looping-and-modifying-a-line-row-by-row with the discussants there making pretty much the same point.

Answer (score 1):

If the command you want to run works with `if`, I think you can achieve this relatively easily. Here I'm calculating the total of `var1`, excluding the Nth row each time:

```
input var1 var2 var3
1.3 4.5 3.3
3.3 2.3 3.6
4.5 1.1 2.2
end

gen results = .
foreach n of numlist 1/3 {
    * Exclude row n from the calculation
    quietly summ var1 if [_n] != `n'
    local total = r(sum)
    * Store the results in the row that is currently excluded
    replace results = `total' if [_n] == `n'
}
```

Comment: Won't this just exclude var1 values?

Comment: The `if [_n] != \`n'` part is the most relevant thing here, and should exclude the entire row. I just used the var1 values in my example command/calculation, but the same should work in a calculation that uses the other variables

Comment: Hmm, I have applied this code and it does not remove the row and just repeats the same command over and over.

Comment: OK, I don't know the specifics of the command you're running so I'm not sure how much more help I can offer. My suggestion works for the example calculation I came up with of "calculate the sum of the var1 column for every row except the current one".

Comment: the command generates a complex statistical analysis for 4 variables and looks at 100 different rows. Your command seems to do the command for everything but the row. Is there a way to temporarily remove the row from the command instead of doing the comand for every row except the row in question?

Comment: You're asking how to modify a program you don't show us. I agree with Marius that there is no obvious need to delete (meaning presumably `drop`) an observation; the tactic is just to ignore it.  For better advice, show us (enough of) the program to make your problem more concrete, or explain fully why the advice in this answer is not good for you.